# Adding new packet scapy: strange bug with random position fields

Tags: python-2.7, scapy

This is the strange comportement:

```
ReturnCodeEnum = {
    0x1: "vardiag",
    0x2: "gambit"
}

TransportSizeEnum = {
    0x10: "No error",
    0x11: "Error: ressource not find",
    0x21: "Error: busy"
}


class UNSPECIFIED(Packet):
    name = "UNSPECIFIED"
    fields_desc = {
        ByteEnumField("returncode", 0x00, ReturnCodeEnum),
        ByteEnumField("transportsize", 0x0, TransportSizeEnum),
        FieldLenField("len", None, length_of="datapart"),
        StrLenField("datapart", "", length_from=lambda pkt: pkt.len)
    }


In [21]: a = UNSPECIFIED()

In [24]: a.show()
###[ UNSPECIFIED ]###
  len       = None
  returncode= 0
  datapart  = ''
  transportsize= 0

In [25]: # Reloading the file
In [26]: a = UNSPECIFIED()

In [27]: a.show()
###[ UNSPECIFIED ]###
  datapart  = ''
  transportsize= 0
  len       = None
  returncode= 0

In [28]: a.show2()
###[ UNSPECIFIED ]###
  datapart  = '\x00\x00\x00\x00'
  transportsize= 0
  len       = 0
  returncode= 0

In [29]:
In [30]: a = UNSPECIFIED()

In [33]: a.show()
###[ UNSPECIFIED ]###
  len       = None
  returncode= 0
  datapart  = ''
  transportsize= 0

In [34]: a.show2()
###[ UNSPECIFIED ]###
  len       = 0
  returncode= 0
  datapart  = ''
  transportsize= 0
```

Packet fields position are not respected. Every time I reload this source, field's positions are changing. I build a lot of scapy packet but it is the first time this bug happens to me. Maybe I dont use correctly the association FieldLenField/StrLenField ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Every time I reload this source, field's positions are changing"*

I could be wrong but as long as your key/value pairs remain the same, I think what you're seeing is the result of dictionaries being inherently unordered. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value
>   pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one
>   dictionary)

A simple test:

dict_order_test.py

```
my_dict = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
print (my_dict)
```

Terminal output:

```
$ python3 dict_order_test.py 
{'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'a': 1}
$ python3 dict_order_test.py 
{'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'c': 3}
$ python3 dict_order_test.py 
{'c': 3, 'a': 1, 'b': 2}
$ python3 dict_order_test.py 
{'c': 3, 'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

To modify what I wrote above slightly, dictionaries *will* have some sort of order but you just can't count on it and it often changes every time you run a script. If I remember correctly, the order is determined by which types of data they contain and how they're hashed internally by Python. Sometimes the order doesn't change, sometimes it does; either way, it's unreliable so use a `list` or an `OrderedDict` if it matters.

Comment: Oh yeah you are right. I have to use a list instead a dict. Thanks for your little mooc.